# failed to insert log files to mongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, log4j, appender

I have 6 microservices, each one generate its own logs and my goal is to insert those logs to mongoDB, so later I'll be able to create a dashboard for logs analysis.

The problem is I don't know how. I thought about NoSQLAppender but i didn't find detailed configuration for spring boot application, i only followed the configuration here and add it to an existing file logback.xml http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#NoSQLAppender 
[image]

but nothing seems to work out,Do you have document or tutorial that provide me with more details because i'm a beginner

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: no, the app acts like the new configuration dosen't exist

Comment: please can you provide me with documentation for nosql appender in spring boot applications because in spring mvc all the config is added in web.xml

Comment: I've no idea but I'll look around and will update if I find anything.